# JAAS user without permission logged in

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss, jaas

I have configured a JAAS login for my web application. The login is configured in `web.xml` as shown below.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/application/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ROLE</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>ROLE</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/login.xhtml?failed=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

For users in `ROLE` everything works as expected. But when I try to access a restricted resource with a user not in the necessary `ROLE`, the login is performed nontheless, an errorpage with code `403` is shown and the user cannot perform a logout (other than deleting cookies or restarting the browser).

Of course I could configure to use a different error page in `web.xml`, which allows logout.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

But my desired behaviour is, that **users who do not have `ROLE` assigned can't login at all and are redirected to the login-page with an appropriate error message**. How can I achieve this?

I don't know whether the information is necessary, but the frontend framework I use is JSF 2.1.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't prevent a legitimate user from authenticating, whether they "belong" to any role(s) or not. The sole workaround is to provide and integrate with the Servlet container your own authentication mechanism that does what you want (i.e., never establish users' authenticated identities unless there are pertinent role memberships). The standard way to do that, as of Java EE 7, is by means of the `javax.security.auth.message` SPI (JASPIC); Java EE 8 will provide convenience-oriented alternatives built atop the former.

Comment: @Uux thank you for that answer. Given this, it is maybe easier to customize the 403 page to be able to logout.